# Is it Possible to Encrypt a JWT token in Php And Decrypt in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, jwt, jwe

I am Currently using two libraries for JWT . First one for server side

[jose php Library](https://github.com/nov/jose-php)

and the second one for client side

[jose js library](https://github.com/square/js-jose)

I am creating a token based login system . All i want is to create a token at server side and after encrypting with JWE(JSON WEB ENCRYPTION) return that token to client and save to html5 local storage .

issue is to decrypt encrypted token in javascript JOSE Library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a [JWE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516) is an standard format, then there is no problem to issue JWE from a platform (PHP, Java, JS...) and read it with another one.

The only problem here is that

- you have to find a library for each platform you want to use.
- these libraries must have common algorithms

I do not know [nov/jose-php](https://github.com/nov/jose-php) but the code review and the tests I performed show me it supports some well-known algorithms (`RSA1_5`/`RSA-OAEP`/`dir` for key encryption and `A128CBC-HS256`/`A256CBC-HS512` for content encryption).

If you use `RSA-OAEP` and `A128CBC-HS256` or `A256CBC-HS512` on your project, then you should be able to encrypt on one side and decrypt on the other side.

If you want to use other algorithms on PHP such as `AxxxKW` or `AxxxGCM`, you should have a look on the [spomky-labs/jose](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/jose) PHP library which supports dozen of algorithms, compression and more.

You should also look at [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) which lists a lot of Jose implementations on several platforms.

### Edit

Private/Public RSA Key Converter

With [`spomky-labs/jose`](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/jose):

```
<?php
use Jose\Factory\JWKFactory;
$key = JWKFactory::createFromKeyFile('/path/to/your/key.pem');
// The variable $key is a JWKInterface instance that can be easily converted into a JSON object: json_encode($key)
```

In pure PHP:

```
<?php
$res = openssl_pkey_get_private($data);
if (false === $res) {
    $res = openssl_pkey_get_public($data);
}
// Verify here that $res is not false.


$details = openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
//Verify here that the array $details has a key 'rsa' (could be 'ec')

$components = [
    'n'  => 'n',
    'e'  => 'e',
    'd'  => 'd',
    'p'  => 'p',
    'q'  => 'q',
    'dp' => 'dmp1',
    'dq' => 'dmq1',
    'qi' => 'iqmp',
];

$key = ['kty' => 'RSA'];
foreach ($details['rsa'] as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($key, $components)) {
        $key[array_search($key, $components)] = Base64Url::encode($value); // Base64 Url Safe encoding. See https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/base64url
    }
}
// The variable $key is an array with the expected information
```

Comment: jose php library uses public key to encrypt and private key to descrypt PEM format and javascript library uses json formated RSA key . So tell me how i can convert my public or private key that is in PEM format to JSON format RSA Key

Comment: I have just updated my answer. I hope it will help you.

Comment: i need same thing in javascript

Comment: The PHP JOSE Library has not been actively supported since the end of 2018. Its security support will terminate on 2020. The library page suggests to use the [PHP JWT Framework](https://github.com/web-token/jwt-framework).